# Solaris encrypt/decrypt similiar on Linux?

Tags: linux, solaris, encryption, openssl

Wondering if someone can help me with they way to use openssl or something similar. In a solaris box normally I'm doing this:

```
decrypt -a aes -k my.key -i mypasswd.aes.cr > /tmp/tmp.file
```

then modify some passwords inside the tmp file, and proceed to encrypt it again

```
encrypt -a aes -k my.key -i /tmp/tmp.file -o mypasswd.aes.cr
```

But in Linux i dont have that solaris commands, so is there a way to do the same thing on linux with same files? I tried with openssl and seems to have a lot of options and parameters. i tried with few of them, like following command:

```
bash-4.2$ openssl  aes-128-cbc -d  -pass file:my.key -in mypasswd.aes.cr -out /tmp/tmp.file
bad magic number
bash-4.2$
```

I don't know what option i need to use, too many!

NOTE:seems like mypasswd.aes.cr is based on default aes 128bits encryption

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to `openssl`, you can use the [OpenSSL `enc` option](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/enc.html) to encrypt/decrypt files.

For example:

```
$ openssl enc -bf -a -in data.txt -out data.enc
enter bf-cbc encryption password:
Verifying - enter bf-cbc encryption password:
```

will encrypt `data.txt` using Blowfish CBC and store the encrypted data in `data.enc` in base-64 encoded format.

You can use a key file with the `-kfile` option:

```
$ openssl enc -aes128 -a -in data.txt -out data.enc -kfile my.key
```

The encrypted data may or may not be compatible with the Solaris `encrypt`/`decrypt` commands. You'll have to test compatibility.

You can enter

```
$ openssl enc ciphers
```

to get a list of ciphers your version of OpenSSL supports.

Note that storing your key file with the data it's protecting isn't very safe.

Comment: Thanks for your replay :). I see, seems I will need to migrate from solaris commands to openssl, maybe trying from the scratch with decrypted file on solaris then encrypt it using linux, so in the futures request i can do it from Linux.